# How to store 50 billion currency value in salesforce?

Tags: currency, long-text-area

```
Long Val1= 50000000000 ;
```

Throws an error Illegal Integer.How would i assign 50 billion value in salesforce ?

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm)?

Answer (score 2):

As a currency, you probably want decimal places, so:

```
Decimal val1 = 50000000000.0;
```

The .0 tells Apex that you want a Decimal value of arbitrary size and precision. This would be appropriate for most cases involving values destined to become part of a calculation involving currency or other fractional values.

Answer (score 0):

Long variables are denoted with L in the end when assigned at compile time otherwise the number are treated as integers. You can also use `Decimal` if that works for you.

```
Long Val1= 50000000000L;
```

Comment: I would think if it's a currency value, Decimal is more appropriate than Long. Usually currencies undergo subsequent calculations and then the cents might matter.